# how to get this json with retrofit

Tags: android, json, http, retrofit, pojo

I'm trying to receive this as a json using retrofit with android studio.

{ 
      "token": "7bf0df45cf2c09f670ubae22af83c98b36d66bf2", 
      "user": { 
        "username": "root", 
        "email": "brianstuffler@hotmail.com", 
        "is_active": true 
      } 
    }

currently this is my code,

```
LoginService loginService = ServiceAuthGenerator.createService(LoginService.class);
        Password = tv_Password.getText().toString();
        Username = tv_Username.getText().toString();
        Userx user = new Userx(Username,Password);

        Call<Userx> call = loginService.getToken(user);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Userx>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Userx> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    Userx user = response.body();
                    SaveToken(user.getToken());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

Userx is my Model class which looks like this with its own getters, setters and constructor.

```
public class Userx {
    private String token;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String name;
}
```

do i have to create another model class that inherit from this one? thanks.

Comment: `"user": { .. }` is a sub object. You could simply create one too. Otherwise you'd probably have to provide a custom deserializer which is usually more work than creating a subclass. Tools like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ can even make you classes from json.

Answer (score 0):

For your pojos to match (and map cleanly to) the Json that you provided, you'd want something like this:

```
public class User {
    private String username;

    private String email;

    @SerializedName("is_active")
    private boolean active;
}

public class Userx {
    private String token;

    private User user;
}
```